# OpenGL not displaying anything?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

My problem is that my program isn't displaying anything on screen.

This is the "main.cpp" code:

```
#include "paStdAfx.h"
#include "OpenGL.h"

HDC hDC = NULL;
HGLRC hRC = NULL;
HWND hwnd = NULL;
HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

const wchar_t* szClassName = _T("*project name :3*");

static std::wstring Titles[] = { 
    _T("*project name :3* - 100% free!"),
    _T("*project name :3* - 100% OpenGL!"),
    _T("*project name :3* - Not cross platform!"),
    _T("*project name :3* - Rawr"),
    _T("*project name :3* - Entirely C++!"),
    _T("*project name :3* - Woo, /r/gamedev!"),
    _T("*project name :3* - Platypi, platypi everywhere."),
    _T("*project name :3* - Nom nom nom"),
    _T("*project name :3* - Thanks, StackExchange!"),
    _T("*project name :3* - DRM Free!"),
    _T("*project name :3* - <3"),
    _T("*project name :3* - Minecraft is also fun!")
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
BOOL CreateOpenGLWindow(const wchar_t*, int, int, int);

OpenGL ogl;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    const std::wstring wtt = Titles[rand() % 11];
    const wchar_t* WindowTitle = wtt.c_str();

    BOOL done = FALSE;
    MSG msg;

    if(!CreateOpenGLWindow(WindowTitle, 800, 600, 32)){ MessageBox(NULL, _T("Could not create window :("), _T("Error!"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    while(!done)
    {
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                done = TRUE;
            else
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ogl.RenderGLScene();
            SwapBuffers(hDC);
        }
    }

    ogl.KillOpenGL(hwnd, hDC, hRC);
    return 0;
}

BOOL CreateOpenGLWindow(const wchar_t* title, int width, int height, int bits)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcx = {0};
    DWORD dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
    DWORD dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;

    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcx.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcx.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcx.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_PROGRAMICON));
    wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcx.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wcx.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcx.hIconSm = (HICON) LoadImage(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_PROGRAMICON), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcx)){ MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to register window!"), _T("Error! :("), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    if(!(hwnd = CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle, szClassName, title, dwStyle, 200, 69, width, height, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL))){ MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to create the window!"), _T("Error! :("), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    ogl.CreateOpenGLContext(hwnd, &hDC, &hRC);
    ogl.PrepareOpenGLScene();
    ogl.ResizeGLScene(width, height);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
    SetFocus(hwnd);

    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            ogl.ProgramIcon(hwnd);
            break;

        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            switch(wParam)
            {
                case VK_ESCAPE:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

and this is the "OpenGL.cpp" code:

```
#include "paStdAfx.h"
#include "OpenGL.h"

GLvoid OpenGL::CreateOpenGLContext(HWND hwnd, HDC* hDC, HGLRC* hRC)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    HGLRC tempContext;

    memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 32;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    *hDC = GetDC(hwnd);

    int PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(*hDC, &pfd);

    if(PixelFormat == 0){ MessageBox(NULL, _T("Could not choose pixel format :("), _T("Error!"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    if(!SetPixelFormat(*hDC, PixelFormat, &pfd)){ MessageBox(NULL, _T("Could not set pixel format :("), _T("Error!"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR); exit(3); }

    tempContext = wglCreateContext(*hDC);
    wglMakeCurrent(*hDC, tempContext);

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if(GLEW_OK != err){ MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to initialize GLEW! :("), _T("Warning!"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION); }

    int attribs[] = {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 1,
        WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB,
        WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
        0
    };

    if(!glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_3_1")){ MessageBox(NULL, _T("OpenGL 3.1 not supported :("), _T("Warning!"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR); }

    if(wglewIsSupported("WGL_ARB_create_context") == 1)
    {
        *hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(*hDC, 0, attribs);
        wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
        wglDeleteContext(tempContext);
        wglMakeCurrent(*hDC, *hRC);
    }
    else{ *hRC = tempContext; }

    const char* GLVersionString = (char*) glGetString(GL_VERSION);
    int OpenGLVersion[2];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &OpenGLVersion[0]);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &OpenGLVersion[1]);
}

GLvoid OpenGL::PrepareOpenGLScene(GLvoid)
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.6f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
}

GLvoid OpenGL::RenderGLScene(GLvoid)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    /* Begin OpenGL Rendering */



    /* End OpenGL Rendering */
}

GLvoid OpenGL::ResizeGLScene(int w, int h)
{
    float ratio = 1.0 * w / h;

    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, ratio, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

GLvoid OpenGL::ProgramIcon(HWND hwnd)
{
    HICON hIcon, hIconSm;

    hIcon = (HICON) LoadImage(NULL, _T("data/icon.ico"), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    if(hIcon)
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hIcon);
    else
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Could not load the big icon! :("), _T("Error!"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    hIconSm = (HICON) LoadImage(NULL, _T("data/icon.ico"), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    if(hIconSm)
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)hIconSm);
    else
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Could not load the small icon! :("), _T("Error!"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
}

GLvoid OpenGL::KillOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC)
{
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(hRC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);
}
```

All the rendering code would go inside the "RenderGLScene" function inside of OpenGL.cpp, but when I place code to render basic things like trianlges or squares on the screen nothing appears. I have tried tinkering with the "gluLookAt()" function and the "gluPerspective()" function as well because I think those might be the source of my problem.  I have tried both VBO and the older method that uses glBegin()/glEnd().

Comment: I see no problem with your gluPerspective call. I don't see gluLookAt anywhere, nor any actual rendering of objects. Please add your actual rendering code, don't leave us to guess as to what you're doing. Also, always put glGetError in your draw loop in at least one place during development, it will tell you if there are problems.

Answer (score 4):

You create a double buffered context, but I don't see you performing a buffer swap (`wglSwapBuffers`) after finishing the rendering. Without a buffer swap you won't see anything.

Comment: In main.cpp SwapBuffers is called right after my rendering function is. I thought that was right, but hey, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What does your render code look like. Remember that the camera always is placed in the origin, which means that you need to draw things at negative z coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a core context all drawing must be done using a VAO. Check the glError() return codes to see what the glDraw*() reports back.

Comment: Meh, `glError` is as annoying as it gets. Use Debug Contexts instead. (if you can, that is)

Comment: It's using a lot of other non-core functionality. Matrix stack, rendering without a shader, etc. And it's requesting a 32-bit depth buffer, which most hardware does not support.

Comment: I'm well aware of that; I did read through the code. The glError codes might not be cool, but they will tell if any of the calls made raise error status. One glError call is sufficient to catch-on if there is anything suspicious going on. Then, sure, it is hard work to binary search the exact spot. But it looks to me he is just trying to get a context going there, using the new extended context creation in wgl so it seems logical first step to see if there is any error, and if so, where. I don't see any added value speculating further until the error state is checked.